# nginx reverse proxy for nginx+gunicorn+django server

Tags: django, nginx, reverse-proxy

A django app is running on django_server.com and I can't get the nginx reverse proxy working to serve that app.
When connecting directly to the django server, let's say `django_server.com` every thing works fine, the user is redirected to `django_server.com/user/login`. The app is running on gunicorn + nginx (upstream and unix socket)

Now all traffic in our organization has to go over one server, lets say `https://www.reverse_proxy.com`, so I added a location `https://www.reverse_proxy.com/django_app`, and I can not get this connection working. The connection to reverse_proxy.com is https, the connection from reverse_proxy.com to django_server.com is http. The reverse_proxy is serving several other site and works, I also tested a connection to the django_server.com with a static html-site, that works, too. So the problem seems so be the django-side, but I can't figure out the error. There are no error-messages in the error logs of both nginxs, it is simply an 404 error.

Here is the nginx-configuration on the django_server.com:

```
#upstream gunicorn_socket { commented out for debugging
#    server unix:/home/django/w_plan/django/fakw/fakw.sock fail_timeout=0;
#}
server {
    server_name django_server.com;
    listen 80 default_server;

location ~ ^/django_app(.*)$ { 
    try_files $uri $1 /$1;
}


location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    #proxy_pass http://gunicorn_socket/; debugging
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000; # debugging

    }

}
```

And here the reverse_proxy:

```
...
location /django_app {
    proxy_pass http://django_server.com:80;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_read_timeout 60;
}
```

Any ideas?

EDIT I:
I've replaced the gunicorn with the django server for debugging and also added the suggestion from @danielgpm

In the django app, for debugging I modified my views.py file:

```
def index(request):
    #return HttpResponse("HelloWorld") # that works
    print(request.META)
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/login/') #does not work
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^user/', include('userauth.urls', namespace='userauth')),
...
```

Now the request.META information should tell me, what goes wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your django app does not have a router for `/django_app` path. You will have to either do a rewrite from /django_app in the reverse_proxy to `/` on the "django_server.com" server or configure a route in your app.

try adding the location below to your `django_server.com` server:

```
... 

location ~ ^/django_app(.*)$ {
  try_files $uri $1 /$1;
}

location / {
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_redirect off;

  proxy_pass http://gunicorn_socket/;
}
```

Comment: now the app can be reached by django_app.com/django_app, but https://www.reverse_proxy.com/django_app still gives a 404 error

Comment: then you most likely have an additional location taking precedence over your `/django_app` location in the reverse_proxy server, try to move it before any `/` location (or temporary comment everthing out except that location to debug. In any case the error.log you be telling you what the issue is at this point...

Comment: when commented out / location and /django_app is the first location, it gives 2 errors in reverse_proxy nginx: ..."/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), ... request: "GET / HTTP/1.1" and ..."/etc/nginx/html/user/login/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), ... request: "GET /user/login/ HTTP/1.1"

Comment: Hmm, Is that the only location there now? If so, it looks to me like a typo or something try putting the exact location you have in your other 'django_server` server.

Comment: ok i ve done some basic debugging at first I replaced the redirect from `/` to `user/login` with a simple HttpResponse("Hello world") and that works from `https://proxy_server.com/django_app` (without the rewrite), so it can't be a typo at the reverse_proxy? So the first error is at the HttpResponseRedirect

Comment: I'm not following, do you have a global rewrite after or before hitting the /django_app? or it is a index directive?please add a more complete section of your configuration file  to be able to help better...